# Assigning to const int *

Tags: c, pointers, constants

```
void main()
{
const int * a;
*a = 5;
}
```

gcc error : assignment of read only location.

so, how to assign to *a, without using another variable?
and what could be a use of a declaration like above?

Comment: Why the "without using another variable" restriction?

Comment: Because otherwise, it's too simple: create a second int *b, assign b = a, then *b = 5 will modify *a.

Comment: Of course it is simple. But it is the answer to the second question: "what could be a use of a declaration like above?".  Oh, and your "b = a" is not strictly correct: it is casting const to non const. You would rather a = b.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
const int * a;
```

Read the declaration from right to left.[See note] What do you get? `a` is a `*` i.e. a pointer to `int` i.e. an integer `const` i.e. a constant. In short, the variable `a` points to an integer whose value you cannot change. At least, not through `a`. Whether the pointee really is immutable or not is a different question. But fact remains, you cannot use `a` to modify `*a`;

`const` is a promise you make to yourself: I will never ever try to modify the pointee using a pointer to a const. The compiler only gives you support.

If you **really** want to write to the pointee, you need a non-const pointer something like:

```
int *a;
*a = 42; /* this is fine */
```

And a very nice comment from [bortzmeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15625/bortzmeyer): (I thought I'd skip this to keep it simple :)

> You can also put the `const` after the `*` (as you said, declarations should be read from right to left).

What he means is this:

```
const int *a;
```

is no different from

```
int const *a;
```

(Remember, the right to left reading rule?)
But is very different from:

```
int * const p;
```

Read it and we get: `p` is a `const`(-ant) `*`(pointer) to `int`(-eger). Translated: once you set `p` to point to an integer, you cannot reseat it (i.e. write to it to make it point to another integer -- the point of making `p` constant), but you can write to the pointee very much (the pointee is not constant).

**Note:** For the pedantically inclined here is 'The Rule' from [Darron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22704/darron):

"declarations should be read from right to left" is a simplification -- if there are parentheses they should be read from inside out. Unless the parentheses indicate a function call. The real rule is "treat it like an expresion; if I apply these operators I'll eventually get this simple type".

This answer really would have had much less meat but for **bortzmeyer** and **Darron** - thank you!

**PPS:** (I promise this is going to be the last edit. Well, hopefully!)

`void main()` is not a standard signature for main in C or C++. Don't use it until you know you or (more importantly) your code will never have to make a voyage to the another universe.

Comment: You got there before me - ya bad Holistic hoor :). I was going to give examples of {int *i;} through to {const int * const i;} and how to read them, but life is too feckin short as it is.

Comment: You can also put the const after the * (as you said, declarations should be read from right to left).

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Not to worry, what goes around, comes around :) For me it's mostly goes around though

Comment: "const is a promise you make to yourself" - this is a great summary of what const is for. Nice one.

Comment: "declarations should be read from right to left" is a simplification -- if there are parentheses they should be read from inside out.  Unless the parentheses indicate a function call.  The real rule is "treat it like an expresion; if I apply these operators I'll eventually get this simple type".

Comment: @Darron: I told myself, this is going to be long enough, let's keep it short and simple. But anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An example illustrating Ruben Bartelink's excellent explanation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int * const a = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if (a == NULL) 
    return 1;
  *a = 3;
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Here, a is constant (and therefore must be initialized) but not *a (probably what the OP wanted).

Comment: NOw compliant with gcc -Wall and splint :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me put your question into simple English.

- If I promise the compiler that I won't write to the value pointed to by the variable a, how do I write to the value pointed to by the variable a?

The answer: change the promise, at least locally.

```
int main()
{
    const int * a;
    *((int *) a) = 5;
}
```

Hopefully the wording above makes it plain that this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for you comments in my post. Please change `void main()` -- that's non-standard (read awful).

Comment: That's what happens when you start by cutting from the question.  :-)

Comment: According to the C/C++ ANSI/ISO standard, casting the l-value is illegal! Some compilers support it as a non-standard extension though, the usage of which is discouraged.

Comment: You can get past the casting limitation with a temporary variable.  Having to do this should make it even plainer that you're doing something less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

you mean `int * const`, not `const int *`.  In one case the pointer is const, the other the stuff it points to is const. You can also do `const int * const`. No harm to read some articles about const_cast, they should cover this ground well.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the point with `const` that you cant assign to it? Although, I dont recall in the case of const pointers if its the value it points to that cant be altered, or the adress of the pointer. Or both. My guess is that neither can be changed.

It can also be a general warning (or error, depending on compiler settings) that you try to write to uninitialized memory.

Correct would be (I assume):

```
void main()
{
   const int* a = new int(5);
}
```

Comment: gcc refuses to recognize "new". So, I have to use C++?

Comment: No, just use malloc() instead of new.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the "how to assign to *a, without using another variable?" but only "what could be a use of a declaration like above?".

It is a promise not to modify the value pointed to.  As discussed in the comment, *if* you make restrictions on the way you allow yourself to use the construct you can arrive at the conclusion that it is not useful.  But if you allow yourself the whole C language then you can find uses.  Think of the prototype of `strcmp` and such.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you've created a pointer, but it doesnt actually point to anything, so when you dereference it (or try to write to its referenced loaction), you get an error.

Comment: No, that's not the only problem: reread the original message, it was a *compilation* error.

Comment: Yes - most modern compilers are able to detect such obvious problems at compile time, rather than runtime, especially in a simple case such as the one cited - you dont need to run the programn to see that there will be an error.

Comment: Again, the problem is NOT the lack of dynamic allocation in the OP question. That's a bug, yes, but even if you fix it, the main problem indicated by the OP will still be there.